# How can I verify in Java that tables have not been modified?

Tags: java, oracle, junit, resultset

I am writing some tests, and I want to verify during these specific tests that my database has not been modified. Is there an easy way to do this that doesn't require me to write individual queries for each table? Basically, I would like something like this:

```
 public Map<String,ResultSet> getDbSnapShot(List<String> tableNames)
 {
     //get rows for specified tables to check from tableNames parameter 
     //returns a map where the key is the table name and the value is the result set
 }

 public void verifySnapShotsAreEqual(Map<String,ResultSet> snapShot1, Map<String,ResultSet> snapshot2)
 {
      //compare snapshot1 and snapshot 2, verify no rows have been modified 
 }
```

Then I would call getDbSnapShot before and after my test and compare the results.

Thanks so much.

Comment: why not use a read only connection/user?

Comment: Because prior to my test I insert some test data in my BeforeClass and I would like to verify the test data hasn't been modified. These tests are also part of a separate project in which the application is running on a vm, so it handles all the real logic. I just invoke methods in the software through mBeans in our jmx console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the **ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS** or **USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS** table and get the required information.

The table have following columns:

- TABLE_OWNER  Owner of the modified table.
- TABLE_NAME   Name of the modified table
- PARTITION_NAME   Name of the modified partition
- SUBPARTITION_NAME    Name of the modified subpartition
- INSERTS  Approximate number of inserts since the last time statistics were gathered
- UPDATES  Approximate number of updates since the last time statistics were gathered
- DELETES  Approximate number of deletes since the last time statistics were gathered
- TIMESTAMP    Indicates the last time the table was modified
- DROP_SEGMENTS    Number of partition and subpartition segments dropped since the last analyze

Before querying table you have to gather statistic data by running GATHER_TABLE_STATS procedure.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2097.htm) [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76992/stats.htm)

Comment: "Query the USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS or USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS." Typo?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get all the records in all the tables in a database it would depend on what database you are using as to exactly what code you would need.

Be aware though, that comparing the data in the tables might not be exactly what you want, comparing the timestamps of the last modification might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a trigger on your database that updates a log table when your tables are modified.

Then check the log table after the tests are run.

Comment: I thought about that but unfortunately I don't have permissions to do that on our database.

Comment: Remember a trigger may be easily enabled and disabled. You could have it enabled only for the test.